# I want to run a php script in background

Tags: php, javascript

I m trying to make messenger kind of service. In which I am facing a problem. I am supposed to reload the page manually. But the problem in running it automatically is that it gets reloaded for every second. I had used a javascript for reloading the page for every 1 sec. Inside which i m calling a php script. But the problem with that code is that complete page gets refreshed. Is there a way to reload only a particular part of the whole page and also i should be able run the php script in the background.

Comment: What you need is AJAX, you can look it up on Google.

Comment: Using jquery library's load function will make it easier to make the AJAX call and updating your html.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Ajax`. [Basic w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Ajax is a group of interrelated web development techniques used on the client-side to create asynchronous web applications. With Ajax, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using the XMLHttpRequest object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not required (JSON is often used instead), and the requests do not need to be asynchronous.

[[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)]

Comment: oh no...more spreading of the w3 schools ajax demo code. whoever wrote it was twacked out on too much coffee when they decided how to indent the code :(